# My Slideshow images are on top of each other???? HTML, JS , CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

So I am trying to make a simple slideshow but for some reason, the images are stacking on top of one another. Is anyone able to help? I have tried everything and nothing seems to change it. I think I may have messed up in the HTML or in the javascript. The images are showing on top of one another instead of in slideshow format but the dots are still appearing underneath and the arrows are still on one of the images
Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numberText">1 / 2</div>
<img src="images/newReleases.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numberText"> 2 / 2</div>
<img src="images/bestSeller.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
}

.next, .prev{
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top:50%;
width: auto;
padding: 15px;
margin-top: -20px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}

.next{
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

.numbertext{
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 12px 12px;
position: absoulte;
top: 0;
}

.dot{
cursor: pointer;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
margin: 0px 3px;
background-color: #ee985b;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover{
background-color: #f6f46c;
}
```

JS:

```
    var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides(){
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";}

slideIndex++;
if(slideIndex > slides.length) {
slideIndex = 1
}

slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your **javascript** it should be `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` and your `var slides` it should be `slides.length`.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

.next,
.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  position: absoulte;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  background-color: #ee985b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #f6f46c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numberText">1 / 2</div>
    <img src="images/newReleases.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numberText"> 2 / 2</div>
    <img src="images/bestSeller.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I am after fixing these problems but there has been no difference in the outcome. Still no slide show appearing

Comment: Try this @sarah https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: You are using `getElementByClassName` instead of `getElementsBysClassName`

Point 2: On your for loop you re using `slide.length` instead of `slides.length` because the slides are set to `slides` variable

Point 3: On your if condition you re using `slide.length` instead of `slides.length` because the slides are set to `slides` variable

Point 4: `slide[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";` instead of `slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";` because the slides are set to `slides` variable

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help, I have fixed all this and I am still having the same problem. Could it be anything else

Comment: Can you try to recreate it via [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then share it here so that we can further check what is happening?

Comment: False alarm, I still was missing a 'slides'. Dyslexia really doesn't help when trying to code! Thanks for all your help!